# How i can select dropdown by its name in cypress?

Tags: cypress

Please click On text for screen shot  :

[Here, I want to delete this posted item by its post name by cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVHjX.png)

[HTML DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSKy3.png)

Cypress code :

```
cy.get('.idea-row').contains(potsname).within(()=>{
        cy.get('.idea-row > .drop-down-menu ').click({force:true})
        cy.get('.idea-row > .drop-down-menu > .options-list').contains('Remove').click({force:true})
    })
```

[Error :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Ozi.png)

Answer (score 1):

[`within()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html#Syntax) command "Scopes all subsequent cy commands to within this element". In other words, the callback in `within()` uses a DOM subtree starting at the element given by the command preceding `within()`.

In your case, it's the element yielded by `contains(postname)` and you're getting an error because you're looking for `.idea-row` element inside this element.

Also, in your case, since the `dropdown-menu` element is not within the element yielded by `contains(postname)`, you'll have to use `contains()` and `within()` this way:

```
cy.contains('.idea-row', potsname).within(()=>{
  cy.get('.drop-down-menu').click({force:true});
  cy.get('.drop-down-menu > .options-list').contains('Remove').click({force:true});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works for me and I understood now

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider upvoting or accepting an answer to encourage more people to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.contains('.idea-row', postname).within(($a)=>{
            // locate all of the spaces 
                if ($a.find('.drop-down-menu > .toggle > .zang-icon').length > 0) {   
                    cy.get('.drop-down-menu > .toggle > .zang-icon').click({force:true})
                    cy.get(' .drop-down-menu > .options-list > :nth-child(1) > .list-row > div > p')
                    .contains('Remove').click({force:true}) // click on "Edit Space" option of first newly created space drp dwn 

                }
            })
```

Above Solutions works for me